# Linux software for comparison of tarballs, SRPMs, and source code files

Tags: linux, debugging, compilation, rpm

I'm looking for software for Linux which can compare source code packages - tarballs, SRPMs and etc. and display the differences in the source code. Can you recommend some good software?

Best wishes

Comment: Unpack them and run `diff -u -r -n` on the two directories?

Answer (score 0):

Try gendiff (usually packaged with RPM).